# Base Clearcase - A particular config spec

Tags: clearcase

I want the LATEST archived elements everywhere except in folder /view/my_view/vobs/the_vob/xxx/yyy/ where I want elements tagged LBL_01. The config spec below doesn't work.

```
element /the_vob/xxx/yyy/... LBL_01
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply the rule directly to `/the_vob/xxx/yyy/`

You need first to select the parent folder versions:

- `/the_vob`
- `/the_vob/xxx`

So:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element /thevob /main/LATEST
element /thevob/xxx /main/LATEST
element /the_vob/xxx/yyy/... LBL_01
element * /main/LATEST
```

The order is important: first select the parent folders, *then* apply your special rules.

Answer (score 0):

If this is on Unix, the VOB tag to use would be /vobs/the_vob and not /the_vob. The path in the element line needs to be the VOB tag as shown by lsvob on the view server.

I am guessing that by "doesn't work" you mean a cleartool ls shows that you're seeing /main/LATEST as the rule.